# Is there any way to play Diablo III in English?

Tags: xbox-one, diablo-iii-console

I have bought a digital version of Diablo III at xbox.com at a South America sale.

My Xbox One region is USA and the language is English. But still when I download the game it only has the Spanish Language.

I can't find a way to play it in English or even buy it again at its North America version this time!

Does anyone have any idea on how I can solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: I know it is possible to change the language. Can't remember now how I did it though. It did require redownloading a load of the files though. This is talking about the pc version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's tied to the store you download from. Since you bought it from the South American XBox.com, you downloaded the spanish version.

You can delete and redownload it (you don't need to buy it again, it'll still be "free" as you already bought the NTSC version), either directly from the xbox one marketplace, or, from the xbox.com US english website. That'll prompt the english version to download.

The link to the US English version is [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/store/p/Diablo-III:-Reaper-of-Souls-%E2%80%93-Ultimate-Evil-Edition/C2R5R5P2DF3C).

Comment: Yesterday I deleted the game from "My Games" and it returned to "Ready to Install". Then I selected the game and downloaded it again. Surprisedly, when it finished the download I open the game and the language remained Spanish. I was sure it would work, that's why I came online to ask for help.

Comment: From what I read you need to download it from the website or marketplace (imagine there are different Diablos with different languages, you can have all of them on your console, they show up as different games). If you just redownload from the same link or entry, it'll be the same language. So you have to manually navigate to the English US version.

Comment: I got it. So what I have to is to delete the game from my console and then access the link you previously posted from a PC and I'll have the option to donwload it direct on my console? Because right now (with the game installed on my console) I accessed the url and there wasn't any option to download, the only information I saw there was a mensage "You own this product".

Comment: Yeah pretty much. I don't have a XBox One, but it was similar process in the 360.

Comment: Alright, I'll try this when I get home. I'll let you know if it works. Thanks!